# for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
    inFile = open("subjects.txt","r") 
    global subArray 
    subArray = [] 
    global line 
    for line in inFile: 
            subArray.append(line) 
    inFile.close() 
    return subArray
```

This how I get the data when in is in different lines in the text file like

```
math
science
art
```

I need to know how to do it when the data is in one line

```
math , science , geography
```

Comment: Name subArray is ambiguous because lists are not called arrays in Python, but lists. array is a class of the module array, to create objects whose elements are homogenous.

Answer (score 4):

`line.split(" , ")` will turn the string into <strike>an array</strike> *a list* of strings. You might also look at the standard "csv" module.

Comment: No. `line.split(" , ")` turns the string into a **LIST** of strings. There are no _arrays_ in Python , apart from the objects of the module **array** that are special.

Comment: @eyquem: Yes, of course you are correct there. I was just using the OP's language. Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will work if the entire file is just one line:

```
subArray = [subj.strip() for subj in open("subjects.txt","r").read().split(',')]
```

or if you want to do it in a loop:

```
 inFile = open("subjects.txt","r")
 subArray = []
 for line in inFile
    for subject in line.split(','):
        subArray.append(subject.strip())
 return subArray
```

or using the csv module:

```
import csv
subArray = []
for line in csv.reader(open('subjects.txt', 'rb')):
   for subject in line:
       subArray.append(subject)
```